# Does someone there experience with resque worker and appfog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, appfog

I couldn't run resque workers in appfog.

Appfog doesn't have console interface to run `$ bin/resque work` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience at AppFog, but I found a similar case sample code.

https://github.com/appfog/af-ruby-resque

It seems that you should write the shell command to run resque workers at manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, committed a month ago :)